# How do I get urllib library to download all the files with .gz extension from one http directory

Tags: python-3.x, http, directory, download, urllib

I have tried to get urllib to download all the files that end with .gz within a directory. My code runs without error but does not download anything. I am not exactly sure what I am doing wrong here. Please help me.

```
from urllib import *
directory = 'https://eogdata.mines.edu/wwwdata/viirs_products/vnf/v30'
with request.urlopen(directory) as doc:
        for line in doc:  
            if line.endswith(b'gz'):
                urllib.request.retrieve(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some few mistakes in your script, first you need to parse the files in the url then check if it is `gz` file or not

I tried to make an example using `urllib2`

```
import urllib2
import re
directory = 'https://eogdata.mines.edu/wwwdata/viirs_products/vnf/v30/'
sock = urllib2.urlopen(directory)
sock.close()
found_files = re.findall(r'href="(.*?)"', sock.read()) # here you parse all the files available for download
for file in found_files:
    if file.endswith('gz'):
        file_location = directory+file # the gz file location
        print "downloading %s from %s" % (file, file_location)
        file_download = urllib2.urlopen(file_location) # get file from url
        with open(file, "wb") as local_file: # open a file with the same name of our gz file
            local_file.write(file_download.read()) # write data to our file
        file_download.close()
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Mobrine the program ran without any problem, but did not download any file. I changed the last urlopen with retrieve but it still did not make any download eventhough there were no errors. I guess something is still wrong somewhere

Comment: From where are you exactly running this python file? if you are not sure where you can open new file in a directory you want by doing something like this `with open("absolute_path_to_your_directory/%s" % file, "wb") as local_file`

Comment: I have added the path as you suggested but still same situation. You might want to run it yourself and see if you could fix it please. It is an open data

Comment: I realized that the find_file parameter holds an empty list, so I think that is the problem, if I can get it to hold the real list of files available for download, I think it will  work. But I am not sure how to fix it. Could you please work that out for me